# No redirecciona al enlace

Tags: php, codeigniter

Buenos días, tengo el siguiente problema, al hacer click en el enlace del menú, no me redirecciona a la vista que quiero, sino que me redirecciona al login....
PD: Al cargar el proyecto carga la vista del login, y hay que iniciar sesión para acceder al index. Eso lo hago con el siguiente controlador:

```
<?php

class cLogin extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mLogin');   
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['mensaje'] = '';
        $this->load->view('vLogin',$data);
    }

    public function ingresar(){

        $nombre_usu= $this->input->post('nombre_usu');
        $pass_usu= $this->input->post('pass_usu');

        $res= $this->mLogin->ingresar($nombre_usu,$pass_usu);

        if ($res ==1) {
            $this->load->view('layouts/header.php');
            $this->load->view('layouts/menu.php');
            $this->load->view('usuarios/vIndex.php');
            $this->load->view('layouts/footer.php');
        } else {
            $data['mensaje'] = "Usuario o contraseña Incorrecta";
            $this->load->view('vLogin',$data);
        }

    }
 }

 ?>
```

El enlace del Menu

```
 <li class="active">
     <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>cCalendar">
         <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> 
         Consultar Horarios
     </a>
 </li>
```

Este es el controlador

```
<?php

class cCalendar extends  CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mCalendar');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('layouts/header.php');
        $this->load->view('layouts/menu.php');
        $this->load->view('usuarios/vCalendar.php');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer.php'); 
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que se ve en tu enlace simplemente estás redireccionando a `base_url()`, lo cual te va a llevar directamente a la función `index` del controlador por defecto que hayas puesto en la variable `$route['default_controller']` del archivo `./application/config/routes.php`, por lo que simplemente tendrías que cambiar tu enlace de la siguiente manera:

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="<?= base_url('index.php/cCalendar'); ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
        Consultar Horarios
    </a>
</li>
```

Debes pasarle un argumento a la función `base_url()` que en este caso es el nombre del controlador al que quieres acceder

El `<?= base_url(); ?>` simplemente se traduce como `<?php echo base_url(); ?>`

Comment: Me sigue redireccionando a http://localhost/SAE/cLogin/ingresar  no tengo idea de porque....

Comment: Tengo en el  routes.php  $route['default_controller'] = 'cLogin';

Comment: @CristianOx21 prueba lo siguiente  <a href="<?= base_url()?>cCalendar">cCalendar">

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, tenía un error, prueba como te digo, cambiando el `base_url()` en tu enlace por `base_url('index.php/cCalendar')`

Comment: Sucede lo mismo....que otro problema podría ser?(te agradezco las respuestas de todas formas) estoy usando AdminTLE(una plantilla free, con bootstrap) pero no creo que sea el problema aunque antes tenia un problema de cookies que no pude solucionar(no se actualizaba el diseño) así que lo comencé desde cero.

Comment: Prueba desde una ventana en modo incognito, puede ser caché

Comment: Era un problema de caché, No se porque sucede, Gracias